# STL algorithms taking the whole container rather than .begin(), end() as arg?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, c++11

Stand-alone STL algorithms (like `std::count_if`) take pair of iterators. In all cases where I use those (and in all examples I've seen online!), I find myself typing

```
std::count_if(myContainer.begin(),myContainer.end(), /* ... */ );
```

Is there a reason why shorthand templates of the style

```
std::count_if(myContainer, /* ... */ );
```

are not provided, given that more of than not is the operaation performed on the whole container? Did I just overlook it? Is the answer different for c++11 and c++03?

Comment: It is a simply a design decision. Many people don't find it such a good choice (see http://www.slideshare.net/rawwell/iteratorsmustgo). Boost provides those algorithms using their Range concepts.

Comment: In C++20, problem's solved (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a nice [blog-post](http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/07/why-no-container-based-algorithms/) by Herb Sutter discussing the question. The gist is that adding container-based overloads for algorithms can create ambiguities if an overload for that algorithm with the same number of template-parameters already exists. Concepts were intended to fix that problem.

Comment: Ok, then `std::count_if_all` or `std::count_all_if` would do the job? Same with `std::sort` (`std::sort_all`) and all others...

Comment: But why not *only* have overloads that operate on containers? Don't say because of flexibility - you can always create a container, or range or tuple of begin and end from an arbitrary begin and end.

Answer (score 2):

STL principle and flexibility is mainly because of operating on iterators instead of containers. It is not a big problem, you can re-use trick I am using from my early C years:

```
#define FULL_RANGE(c) (c).begin(), (c).end()

std::copy(FULL_RANGE(c), std::ostream_iterator<c::value_type>(cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: That's a clever trick actually, though I'd probably call it ALL and nowadays use std::begin and std::end

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be to provide the **flexibility for iteration range**. You may not want to traverse through all the elements sometimes:

```
<iterator> it = myContainer.begin();
it++; // do something
it++; // do something
...
std::count_if(it, myContainer.end(), /* ... */);
```

OR

```
std::count_if(myContainer.begin(), myContainer.end() - N, /* ... */);
```

---

BTW, you can always have a wrapper which does this for you:

```
template<typename T>
auto count_if (T& myContainer, /* ... */)
{
  return std::count_if(myContainer.begin(), myContainer.end(), /* ... */ );
}
```

Comment: In C++11, use `begin(myContainer)` and `end(myContainer)` in order to make it work with arrays as well.

Comment: The 0.1%-case where you need to iterate only over a part of the container justify typing `.begin()` and `.end()`  in the 99.9% cases, if it is possible to have both.

Comment: @Euxodos: Yes, those 0.1% of cases would be trivially solved with `count_if(make_range(it, myContainer.end()), /*...*/);`. - Historically it seems that algorithms were added to the standard library in a hurry, and iterators were such a novel idea at a time. Had they had a bit more experience with them, things could have turned out different. But now it seems, they can't let go of the old things, and can't add new things, unless it can be done cleanly.

Comment: Taking iterators doesn't provide any more flexibility. You can always create a container, or range or tuple of begin and end or whatever you call it, from an arbitrary begin and end.

Comment: @Neme, With the updated answer, it will be more clear about what point I was trying to make. You and I are discussing a different point. :-) OP wants to know why certain functions accepts `.begin / .end` pair intead of the full container. One of the reason is that, passing a full container will force the user to traverse through all the elements. Which is not the case when the iterators are passed.

Comment: I am talking about the same thing. How would taking a full container force the user to traverse through it? It wouldn't. It has the same benefits and drawbacks as taking begin and end iterators.

Answer (score -1):

Simply because STL algorithms are connected / talks with container using iterators.